# easiest way to store user data/input in a application

Tags: bada

what is the easiest way to store e.g. a list of strings in the application, so when the user start the app again i can simply read it out again and work on the stored list of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use registry.
OSP::IO::Registry.
You can persist the values in a registry file and store in your addplication's data folder.